# S05E01 Ιs the man who talked to the sanctuary people Νegan?

Tags: the-walking-dead

At the end of the episode a man is talking to the sanctuary people who are trapped in a box.
Could this man possibly be [Negan](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Negan)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to creator Robert Kirkman, he is [definitively *not* Negan](https://twitter.com/RobertKirkman/status/521490135909949440).

> That was NOT Negan at the end of the episode. Note the face tattoos.

The role of ["Crazed Man"](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Crazed_Man), or the "Large Man", [as named by showrunner Scott Gimple](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/walking-dead-who-is-mystery-739978)  is played by actor Owen Harn.

[image: Large/Crazed Man]

> The part of the "large man," as showrunner Scott M. Gimple called him, was played by Owen Harn, and was indeed the same man who was later devoured by walkers after his group invaded Terminus and was captured and held captive by Gareth's group. (Sorry, diehard comics fans, it's not Negan.)

He explains...

> "He is the guy who has been torturing them in the flashback; they've locked him up and he's been kept in there ever since they took the place," Lincoln says, noting the character "isn't a factor anymore" — at least in the present day.
> Gimple tells THR that the character has a backstory with "a lot to the character," including a backstory and that the zombie drama may indeed reveal that the "large man's" group was connected to another band of crazies.

While he is *not* Negan, Negan [*may* show up in season 5](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/walking-dead-season-five-negan-722002) (warning: major comics spoiler in that article if you're not already with familiar with Negan and what he does).

> While producers have repeatedly said that they wouldn't get to the character in season four, it's unclear if that same thought applies for the upcoming fifth season of AMC's zombie drama.
>
> (snip)
>
> "I love the different places we've been able to go with Negan and his [F-bomb-laden] vocabulary. … It's been a lot of fun and I'm as excited about bringing that character into the show as the fans are. … But we don't want to rush it and we have to do it the right way," he said of adding Negan to the AMC series. "If we introduced Negan 20 issues earlier in the comic, it wouldn't have been as cool. We're going to make sure we take our time and do it the right way."

Answer (score 5):

[**No, he is not Negan.**](https://twitter.com/RobertKirkman/status/521490135909949440)

[image]

I really thought that that was Negan as well.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I hope we will see him one day :)

Comment: Well, we saw him die in the "present", so anything we see again will be a flashback.